# Simplifying expressions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, computer-algebra-systems

I have a polynomial ring $R=k[x,y,z...]$ and a given ideal $I$ (defined by given generators) and several polynomials $f_1,f_2,...$ in the ring. I also have several other elements of $R$ given as polynomials in $f_1,f_2,...$ and $x,y,z...$. I wish to determine whether these elements lie in the ideal or not. I do not have exact expressions for $f_1,f_2,...$ but I know certain relations that hold between these and the indeterminates. Now, my problem is computational. I wish to simplify the expressions I have to a more manageable form where I am able to "see" the membership. So I was wondering whether there are any softwares that will allow me to automate this. Essentially I would like to feed the relations to the software, and it should simplify the expression as much as possible using these relations. So far I have tried Maple and Matlab, but both of those require too much manual intervention. For example the expression I have may have a term like $f_1(x+f_1)$ and I have a relation $f_1^2=f_2+f_3$. Then I would like the term simplified to $xf_1+f_2+f_3$. Is there any software that might help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Singular](http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/) or [CoCoA](http://cocoa.dima.unige.it/) or [Macaulay2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/).

Comment: Thanks. I have used Macaulay2Sage before, but I am not sure how to handle these type of problems in that. I will look at Singular and CoCoA.

Comment: @Kyle, I'm not sure they can handle your problem, but I thought I'd mention those programs just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Any computer algebra system supporting Grobner bases will suffice, e.g. in Macsyma

$\rm (c_1)\ \ grob\_tot\_reduce(\ f_1*(x+f_1),\ [\:f_1^2-f_2-f_3],\ [\:x,f_3,f_2,f_1]);$

$\rm(d_1)\ /R/\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad x\ f_1 + f_2 + f_3$

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I actually get this? Do I need to define any ambient ring or something. When I typed the above command in Macsyma, the output was exactly what I had typed. Nothing else.

Comment: Never mind that. What I downloaded was Maxima which is based on Macsyma. I don't have access to Macysma, so I will keep looking for another way.

Comment: If you're using the free version Maxima then you may need to load grobner first (googling shows it does have some version of grobner). Alas, I don't recall the differences (Maxima is based on a *very* old version of Macsyma). Try the support email list http://sourceforge.net/mail/?group_id=4933

Comment: Thanks again, Bill. Douglas Leonard over at Macaulay2 google group helped me with the relevant Macaulay2 code, which solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Maple you could use simplify with respect to side relations:
http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=simplify%2Fsiderels

The input for your example would be:
simplify( f1*(x+f1), [f1^2 = f2+f3] );